# How do I break an array into smaller arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is what I want to do. I have an array that I then want to split up into all the elements that it has. For example I have:

```
$originalArray = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

And I want to split this array to look like this.

```
$array1 = array(1);
$array2 = array(2);
$array3 = array(3);
$array4 = array(4);
$array5 = array(5);
```

if the original array had more elements then I would like it to split into all those arrays.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($originalArray); $i++ ){

    /*this is where I am stuck, I would like it if the word "array" would be able to concat with the iterator $i to make $array1, $array2 and so on*/ 

    $array.$i = array($originalArray[$i]);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$originalArray = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$temp = array();
$i=1;
foreach ($originalArray as $elem) {
  $temp['array' . $i] = $elem;
  $i++;
}
extract($temp);
print_r($array1);echo '<br/>';
print_r($array2);echo '<br/>';
print_r($array3);echo '<br/>';
print_r($array4);echo '<br/>';
print_r($array5);echo '<br/>';
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/VrVoNgm3)

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 1));
?>
```

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$originalArray = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$splitArray = explode(",",$orginalArray);

for($i = 0; $i < count($originalArray); $i++ ){


    $array.$i = array($splitArray($i));


}
```

Comment: Fatal error:  Function name must be a string at `$array.$i = array($splitArray($i));`